# There is a bug that returns to start when resizing with scrollTrigger.(GSAP)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, gsap

I am Japanese and I am writing this question using a translation app. Therefore, please understand that I may not be able to convey the intent of your question well.
*I would appreciate it if you could answer in sentences that are easy to translate.

I think you can see the results of codepen,
This scrolltrigger's timeline reverts to the start of the animation when it is resized. Also, when resizing from mobile size to PC size, the screen does not resize, only the white margin expands.

Presumably, this phenomenon occurs when the width exceeds the width specified in matchmedia.

How can I resize it so it doesn't bug me?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/zumi999/pen/jOXOjdP)

```
const tl = gsap.timeline({
scrollTrigger: {
trigger: area,
start: "top top",
end: "+=20000",
scrub:1,
pin: true,
ease:Power0.easeNone,
invalidateOnRefresh: true,
anticipatePin: 1,
saveStyle:true,
}
```

});